# For attacks with ranged weapons, is the attacker's Dexterity bonus added to the damage roll?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, ranged-attack

In 5th edition combat, does a character using a ranged weapon like a bow or crossbow get to add their dexterity to their damage? Such as a rogue with a 15 Dexterity using a light crossbow, would they deal 1d8+2 damage?

Comment: Related: [Do Crossbows add Dex to damage?](/questions/70538)

Comment: Though the titles may seem similar, the linked question is asking whether a rule from past edition about crossbows specifically carries over to 5e. The asker of that question was already aware of the rule this question is asking about, and that question was asking whether crossbows were an exception to the rule. They're definitely not duplicates.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Yes, a ranged attack with a ranged weapon would include your Dex bonus to both attack and damage rolls.

The *Player's Handbook* mentions this twice.

First in chapter 7 ("[Using Ability Scores](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#AbilityScoresandModifiers)") regarding Dexterity:

> Dexterity Attack Rolls and Damage
>
> You add your Dexterity modifier to your attack roll and your damage roll when attacking with a ranged weapon, such as a sling or a longbow.

This is stated again in chapter 9 ("Combat") under the section "[Making an Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MakinganAttack)":

> To make an attack roll, roll a d20 and add the appropriate modifiers. ...
>
> The ability modifier used for a melee weapon attack is Strength, and the ability modifier used for a ranged weapon attack is Dexterity. Weapons that have the finesse or thrown property break this rule.

So yes, for a character with 15 Dexterity (i.e., +2 modifier), they would normally calculate the crossbow's damage roll as 1d8+2.

Note that this only applies to ranged *weapon* attacks. Ranged *spell* attacks usually don't use Dexterity.

> Some spells also require an attack roll. The ability modifier used for a spell attack depends on the spellcasting ability of the spellcaster.

Comment: Of note, your header says "ranged weapon attacks" which are not the same as "attacks with ranged weapons", for example, the first includes thrown weapons, the second does not.

Comment: For completeness, it should say ranged attacks with ranged weapons - otherwise someone will try to get that bonus when they swing their bow at someone...

Comment: @Davo Fixed again, with even properer semantics.

Comment: @Davo a ranged attack with a ranged weapon would still let you *throw the bow* adding the first word "ranged" there is, in my opinion, unhelpful. This is because of the unintuitive rule that if you make an improvised attack with a weapon the weapon is no longer a melee or ranged weapon. It is an improvised weapon that is being used to make a melee or ranged attack

Comment: That's a good point.